# Cannot edit posts when reviewing first and late Q&A

Tags: support, review

Sometimes when I am reviewing the late and new posts queue I am unable to edit the post currently being reviewed. First I thought this might be because someone else has made an edit waiting for approval, but after doing some more reviews, I don't think this is the case.

I don't understand what the requirements are for being allowed or not allowed to edit posts when reviewing. Could someone refer to the page specifying this or explain it?

Comment: Can you provide links to examples of posts you can and can't edit?

Comment: It has been a couple of days since I had one of these non-editable reviews. I will keep this in mind and when I get one of these again, I will post it here.

Comment: I've run into a similar problem the past couple days. I click `Edit` from First Answer (or Late Answer) Review and it pulls up the Edit post page. However, I cannot move the cursor in the editing text box by clicking with the mouse. I can edit the post by moving the cursor with the keyboard, but this is tedious and annoying. Also, I must hit `Tab` to enter a description of my edits; I cannot click into the Description text box.

Comment: FYI, I am using Firefox 28.0

Comment: @nhinkle See my previous comments. This problem is persisting for me -- just happened again in Low Quality Post review.